# How to run all pytest tests with extra function calls using class

Tags: python, pytest, python-unittest

I have a base class called BaseTest which all my test cases are inheriting from.

Each TestCase have X tests and a method - different_configuration()

Instead of creating test_xyz and test_xyz_different for each test (which means to double my tests in the code, and even more if I'll have x different configurations)

Is there a way to make the base class have something or even a fixture which per existing test will create/run another test but will call self.different_configuration() at the beginning.

EXTRA INFO -
I have a dict as an attribute which has configurations and, there's one configuration, which for each test I'd like to test both available options.

self.different_configuration() just changes the configuration value before the test itself.

Illustration -

```
    def test_x(self):
        self.run_and_verify()

    def test_x_different_configuration(self):
        self.different_configurations()
        self.run_and_verify()
```

So for each existing test I create another test with this function call at the beginning, isn't there a cleaner way to achieve it?

Comment: Have you tried using `pytest.mark.parametrize` ? https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/parametrize.html If that's not enough for your use case, I think you will need to write a plugin that modifies the test collection.

Comment: If you want to try the test collection route, maybe you can use this hook https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/reference.html?highlight=hooks#pytest.hookspec.pytest_collection_modifyitems

Comment: I can do it with parametrize but it will be ugly that for each test I will HAVE to have parametrize with sort of the same values, it seems like repeat of un-necessary code.

Comment: How can I use that hook? I read a little but diden't quite understand how can it help me.

Comment: You can place the hook function in your `conftest.py` and it will be called with the params `session, config, items`. `items` is the list of tests that will be executed and you can append new items to it. For example, you can easily duplicate items in that list and the tests will be executed several times. However, I'm not sure if you could actually call your `different_configurations` from there.

Comment: But you could possibly add a new marker to each item. For example the `parametrize` one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [parametrize a fixture](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/fixture.html#parametrizing-fixtures).

You will have to extract your configuration values from the dictionary to a list, though, to use it on the `params` argument.

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture(scope="module", params=[config1, config2])
def different_configuration(request):
    return request.param
```

Then, on your test, you can use each configuration value somehow to change the configuration as you want:

```
def test_x(self, different_configuration):
    self.different_configurations(different_configuration)
    self.run_and_verify()
```

Or something like that.